# Pushing a View on Navigation stack

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

How is a ViewController object pushed into view via the navigationController if the object is created in another class than the one which should push the view.

The problem I had is in the class where I created the object and set its values, I had no access to the main navigationController. when I called [self.NavigationController .... It is undefined.

How is this navgation controller accessed? or how can I create a viewController object in one class and set values/push the object into view via another class?

Comment: i'm confused.. can you rephrase that question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose classA- mainViewController
and classB- userDetailVC

pass the Object to classB before its push on Stack

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender{

    UserDetailVC* userDetailVC=[[UserDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserDetailVC" bundle:nil];
    [userDetailVC autorelease];
    //imp- set the object over here
        NSDictionary* tempDict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.userInfoDict];
        userDetailVC.userInfoDict=tempDict;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:userDetailVC animated:YES];

}
```